# CoffeeScript 'in' not like Python's

Tags: coffeescript

CoffeeScript:

```
list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
console.log [0, 0] in list     #false
console.log [1, 0] in list     #false
console.log [0, 1] in list     #false
console.log [1, 1] in list     #false
```

Python:

```
>>> lst = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
>>> [0, 0] in lst
True
>>> [1, 0] in lst
True
>>> [0, 1] in lst
True
>>> [1, 1] in lst
False
```

How would I make CoffeeScript replicate Python's 'in' for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work the way you want actually, but its by reference:

```
item1 = [0, 0]
item2 = [0, 1]
item3 = [1, 0]
item4 = [1, 1]

list  = [item1, item2, item3]

console.log item1 in list # true
console.log item2 in list # true 
console.log item3 in list # true
console.log item4 in list # false
```

To make it work by deep check instead of reference, you would have to fork the coffee-script compiler, add this feature to the coffee-script language, then submit a pull request, convince the gatekeepers that this is a good feature and hope they merge it in.

```
list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
contains = (lst, compare) ->
  ret = true for l in lst when l[0] is compare[0] and l[1] is compare[1]       
  return Boolean ret

console.log contains list, [0, 0] # true
console.log contains list, [1, 0] # true
console.log contains list, [0, 1] # true
console.log contains list, [1, 1] # false
```

Comment: I double checked, it wont that easily

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript translates `item1 in list`  to (ignoring the patch that handles browsers without `indexOf`):

```
list.indexOf(item1) >= 0;
```

So it is constrained by how Javascript codes `indexOf`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

This would be, roughly, equivalent to a Python list search that uses `is` to compare `item1` and `list[i]`.  Compare these 2 python statements

```
[[0,1] is l for l in alist]
[alist[1] is l for l in alist]
```

To write a Coffeescript (or Javascript) that behaves the same as Python, you need a way of comparing two arrays.  Compare

```
[0,1]==[0,1]
```

in all 3 languages.  It is true only Python.

`underscore` implements a deep comparison:

> isEqual_.isEqual(object, other) 
>   Performs an optimized deep comparison between the two objects, to determine if they should be considered equal.

Using that I can define a function which returns the item if found, undefined if not

```
ud = require 'underscore'
myin = (list, item)->
  ud.find(list,(x)->
    ud.isEqual(item,x))
myin(list,[0,0])
    # [ 0, 0 ]
myin(list,[0,3])
    # undefined
myin(list,[0,1])?
    # true
myin(list,[2,2])?
    # false
```